# Direct connection between Internet nodes behind masqueraders?

Tags: tcp, ip-address, ipv6, static-ip-address, dynamic-ip

Is there any way to make direct connections (to reduce server load) between Internet nodes behind masqueraders?

In practice, masqueraders are wifi routers or modems.

Can the problem be solved in practice using IPv6? (Do most of the modern routers still use masquerading with IPv6?)

Comment: Look at technologies like webRCT (on mobile at the moment, so it is hard to get a link to some documentation)

Comment: @Ferrybig It seems you dig in a wrong direction: I need it on TCP/IP level not on the level of browsers.